# How can I create a numeric array based on the number of array objects in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array object called `members?.admins`. I want to create an array of numbers based on the length of `members?.admins`.

As an exception, if the length of members?.admins is 1 to 5, [1] should be given as the default value. That is, the default value must be unconditionally `[1]`.

If the number of `members?.admins` is 5, I want to make `[1]` in numbers, and if there are `10`, I want to make `[1,2]`. Also, if there are `11`, it should be `[1,2]`

At this time, I want to use `useEffect` to setNumbers on the first render to create an array of numbers in numbers.

How can I do that?

```js
const members?.admins = [{memberId:"21",name:"jack21"},{memberId:"20",name:"jack20"},{memberId:"14",name:"jack14"},{memberId:"13",name:"jack13"},{memberId:"11",name:"jack11"},{memberId:"10",name:"jack10"},{memberId:"7",name:"jack7"},{memberId:"4",name:"jack4"},{memberId:"3",name:"jack3"},{memberId:"2",name:"jack2"},{memberId:"1",name:"jack1"}];
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1]);

useEffect(() => {
  setNumbers();
}, []);
```

Expected output:

```
  if members?.admins.length =  1~5
    it shuld be 
    number = [1]
    
    if members?.admins.length = 6~10
    it shuld be 
    number = [1,2]

    if members?.admins.length = 11~15
    it shuld be 
    number = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to provide a list of inputs and the expected outputs for a range of values.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok i will do it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let members = {admins: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}

console.log(Array(Math.ceil((members?.admins.length || 0) / 5)).fill(undefined).map((el, i) => i + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can create array using length

```
useEffect(() => {
  const array = [...Array(Math.ceil( members?.admins.length / 5))].map((_, i)=> i+1)
  setNumbers(array);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let admins = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"];
let result = Array.from({length: Math.ceil(admins.length / 5)}, (_, i) => i + 1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.ceil` to get the required length and then fill the array later.

```js
const members = {
  admins: Array(6)
}

const reqLength = Math.ceil(members?.admins?.length / 5);

const reqArray = Array(reqLength).fill().map((v, i) => i + 1);
console.log(reqArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const members?.admins = [{memberId:"21",name:"jack21"},{memberId:"20",name:"jack20"},{memberId:"14",name:"jack14"},{memberId:"13",name:"jack13"},{memberId:"11",name:"jack11"},{memberId:"10",name:"jack10"},{memberId:"7",name:"jack7"},{memberId:"4",name:"jack4"},{memberId:"3",name:"jack3"},{memberId:"2",name:"jack2"},{memberId:"1",name:"jack1"}];
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1]);

useEffect(() => {
    let number = [];
    let mb_length = members?.admins.length;
    if(mb_length%5 === 0){
        let mbb = (mb_length - mb_length%5)/5;
        number = Array.from({length: mbb}, (_, i) => i + 1)
    }else{
        let mbb = (mb_length - mb_length%5)/5;
        number = Array.from({length: mbb+1}, (_, i) => i + 1)
    }
    
    
  setNumbers(number);
}, []);
```